# Is there any macro like __arm64e__ in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, arm64

`__arm64__` is very helpful, but I can't find a macro like `__arm64e__`. Is there any way we can know if the CPU is arm64e?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's called `__arm64e__`.

But note that this doesn't actually tell you what CPU you're running on, only what CPU you *compiled* for. And as it currently stands, the arm64e ABI is not stable and Apple will not accept apps with arm64e slices into the App Store.

Comment: Thanks! But I want to distinguish between arm64 and arm64e as they need to run different code in runtime. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If your arm64 slice ends up running on arm64e, do you still need to run the arm64e variant?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xcode > Build Settings and search VALID_ARCHS like below

[image]

Comment: So is this a user defined macro?